# Decrypting simple script using AES CBC in PHP - migrating from Python

Tags: python, php, encryption, aes, cbc-mode

Currently this code runs in Python, without issue :

```
#!/usr/bin/python   
print('Content-type: text/html\r\n\r')


#! /usr/bin/env python -2
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
#
# PICCData decryption
# PICCData = AES-128_DECRYPT(KSDMMetaRead; PICCDataTag[||UID] [||SDMReadCtr]||RandomPadding)
IV = 16 * '\x00'
key = 16 * '\x00' # FileAR.SDMMetaRead Key
# Enc_PICC_Data = '\xEF\x96\x3F\xF7\x82\x86\x58\xA5\x99\xF3\x04\x15\x10\x67\x1E\x88'
Enc_PICC_Data = 'EF963FF7828658A599F3041510671E88'
myaes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=IV)
PICCData = myaes.decrypt(unhexlify(Enc_PICC_Data))

print (hexlify(PICCData))
```

Response is :

```
b'c704de5f1eacc0403d0000da5cf60941'
```

I am unable to essentially migrate this code over. I have tried variations of the following which does not return any response no matter what I do. I might be doing something painfully stupid :

```
$e = 'EF963FF7828658A599F3041510671E88';
$key = '00000000000000000000000000000000';
$iv = '00000000000000000000000000000000';

$output = openssl_decrypt($e, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, 0, $iv);
echo $output;
```

Many thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 issues with your code.

First: you are using input values in form of hexstring values - they have to be transformed to binary data with **hex2bin**.

Second: Your PHP script is using a **random padding** so it adds some data to makes the output looking different each time it runs. For decryption only the first 16 bytes (32 hexstring characters) will be used (those in your $e variable) you have to force
OpenSSL to deny any padding - that's what the option "**OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING**" is good for.

Third: The other option "**OPENSSL_RAW_DATA**" is forcing OpenSSL to take raw data instead of base64-encoded data.

Put all three parts together in the code you receive the expected plaintext (here in hexstring): c704de5f1eacc0403d0000da5cf60941

console:

```
output: ��_��@=  �\�    A
output in hex: c704de5f1eacc0403d0000da5cf60941
```

**Security warning: the following code is UNSECURE (e.g. static key & iv) and has no exception handling!**

code:

```
<?php
$e = hex2bin('EF963FF7828658A599F3041510671E88');
$key = hex2bin('00000000000000000000000000000000');
$iv = hex2bin('00000000000000000000000000000000');

$output = openssl_decrypt($e, 'AES-128-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
echo 'output: ' . $output . PHP_EOL;
echo 'output in hex: ' . bin2hex($output);
?>
```

Comment: Ah that is fantastic, I had actually done more or less this, but missed out the key with hex2bin. Thank you ever so much, that is a great answer too.